# Subversion - Moving files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to move a project from one location in the SVN to another without losing the history of changes?

Comment: Getting an RTFM as answer can be discouraging, but you have to admit that the OP could have typed "svn move history" into google and would have gotten his answer immediately that way.

Answer (score 14):

yes.

The other answers describe command line svn - this one is for the tortoise GUI:

From http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html

If you want to move files around inside your working copy, perhaps to a different sub-folder, use the right-mouse drag-and-drop handler:

1. select the files or directories you want to move
2. right-drag them to the new location inside the working copy
3. release the right mouse button
4. in the popup menu select Context Menu → SVN Move versioned files here

this will preserve the history

Answer (score 5):

While using TortoiseSVN you can simply drag files with your **right** mouse button and select appropriate option from the context menu after dragging ended.

Take a look at this page for clarification:
http://tortoisesvn.net/most-forgotten-feature

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the command

```
svn move
```

Another one that might work for you is:

```
svn copy
```

Both should keep the revision history of the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about moving the repository from one server to another, take a look at:

- [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html)
- [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html)

Otherwise, within the same repository, you can use the copy or move commands:

- [svn copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html)
- [svn move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html)

In either case, the history will be preserved. With the dump and load, you have to be careful that all of the users of the repository switch to the new one at the same time, otherwise you may lose some data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `svn move` preserves the history of files that are moved. If you are re-casing a filename, the answer is more complex. See the SVN FAQ: http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#case-change